# Find the value of $\lambda$ in this humongous limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^{mr}\frac{mn^2}{(m^2n^2+k^2)(n^2+r^2)}\right)\right)\right)=\frac{\lambda\pi^2}{160}$$ Then find the value of $\lambda$.

I saw this on telegram. It's my first time to see summation involved in limits. Actually I don't know how to solve these type of questions. But here is my work that I did.

Since, both $m$ and $n$ are tending to $\infty$ we can re write this as  (I'm pretty sure that what I'm doing is not correct)
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{mn^2}{(m^2n^2+k^2)(n^2+r^2)}\right)$$ and now we can calculate this (hopefully)

I'm stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that as $n$ and $m$ both also appear in the terms of the sums

Comment: You can try to switch to Riemann sums:
$$S=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n^2}{n^2+r^2}\sum_{k=1}^{mr}\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{n^2+\big(\frac{k}{m}\big)^2}\to\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n^2}{n^2+r^2}\int_0^r\frac{dx}{n^2+x^2}$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+\big(\frac{r}{n}\big)^2}\int_0^r\frac{\frac{1}{n}\,dx}{1+\big(\frac{x}{n}\big)^2}$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav do we have to apply high level advanced math in this question...as i don't think this is the case cuz the grp from where i got this is not college or university level...nevertheless i like your approach

Comment: I believe this is a shortcut, but other methods are applicable, for sure.

Comment: Is this really "not college level"? I consistently get the same culture shock. Where I'm from, there's no way in hell a pre-uni student is expected to / is taught to handle such a question by the standard school system

Comment: I mean even in my place, riemann sums aren't taught...I'm just guessing as it came in that group...but it can be of college level also

Comment: The Riemann sums yield: $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\lambda\pi^2}{160}$$And the notion of a Riemann sum is likely the easiest way to evaluate this.

Comment: @FShrike omg bro...you just obliterated the problem...can you pls write this as an answer ...as i also want to know the intermediate steps and also to upvote you

Comment: I merely followed on from Svyatoslav's hint

Comment: @FShrike i mean you can explain me some of it, if you wish

Comment: I recommend you think about Svyatoslav's work, and get back to either of us about any particular troubles you've had with it